# Yii - 'white screen of death', debugging tips

Tags: php, debugging, yii, frameworks

I have a staging server running a Yii application that now gives a 'white screen of death'. I cannot see anything being ouputted to the screen (or even the source code when 'view source'), locally the same code runs without any issues.

Can anyone suggest a good routine to debug 'white screen of death' within a Yii application?

Comment: Check that your PHP ini has `display_errors=true`. This gave me about 3 hours worth of headaches sometime ago

Comment: I would appear to be getting an '500 Internal Server Error' in the browser console log

Comment: Not if your server doesn't even report the error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getting a blank screen in yii is mostly because error_reporting is off.
Put

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

in index.php should get your output back.

Note that you can always look in application.log and apaches error.log for informations when you don't have some output.

Comment: Wasted 2 hours before landing this ques.. Thank you. It saved my day

Answer (score 0):

This is for Yii2

I found the code was failing in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php at method autoload($className).  It was failing at execution:

include $classFile;  (line 293)

The cause in my case was a function method name declared twice.

You might be interested to know that you can discover the cause (which Yii2 suppresses through its own error-handling) by preceding the command with Chris's recommended code above https://stackoverflow.com/a/25139283/3125602. If you introduce them too early in the code, they get overwritten by Yii2's error-handling settings.

Answer (score -1):

It is quite a simple issue and happens either when a script reaches the PHP memory limit or during a plugin or theme conflict.

Solutions :

1. **Increase the Memory Limit :**

Since this is regarded as one of the cause, it is recommended that the PHP memory limit be increased. Edit your wp-config.php file via FTP adding the following line of code:
define( ‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘64’);

This increases your memory limit to 64M. You might need to contact your host before you do it as some host don’t allow it from your end.

2. **Deactivate all your Plugins :**

Connect to your site via FTP and rename the wp-content/plugins folder to plugins_old to deactivate all your plugins.

Here is a detailed answer to the infamous "White Screen of Death" problem. Thank me later :)

https://www.perceptionsystem.com/blog/wordpress-errors-solution/