# php readability can't find the content and return error

Tags: php, html, css, yii

I have installed **[php-readability](https://github.com/feelinglucky/php-readability)** But i have problem with this in one of my websites.

When the safe mode of host, was inactive, it returned Nothing (white page) and no content of any URL.

But when the safe mode get on, I see this error :

> Warning: curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be
>   activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in
>   /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/php-readability-master/index.php
>   on line 44
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
>   'Readability was unable to parse this page for content.' in
>   /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/php-readability-master/lib/Readability.inc.php:270
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/php-readability-master/index.php(63):
>   Readability->getContent() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/php-readability-master/lib/Readability.inc.php
>   on line 270

What should i do ?

What is the problem ?

How can i solve this ?

CURL is active + I addeed curl_setopt_array function but it didn't worked again !

Comment: Given error message is self-explaining. You have to dive to the sources and disable `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option.

Comment: @hindmost tnx, How to disable it ?

Comment: Just comment the line (44) containing `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` key

Comment: @hindmost Nothing changed :(

Answer (score 1):

PHP safe mode restrictions with cURL: [disable safe mode on your PHP server setup if you have PHP >= 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918623/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated)

White screen on browser with PHP/Yii app: probably you have an [unexpected / uncaught PHP fatal error, hidden in your PHP setup and/or Yii app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139197/yii-white-screen-of-death-debugging-tips).